# Not getting all data when making .ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to get data from a page that generates the following object displayed as text in the body and pre tag, but it seems not to get all 4 key|value pairs (only 3)?

Please note that I have changed the urls of the jSON output and and removed most of the data to shorten it here. hopefully I didn't introduce any errors.

```
{"nodes":[{"node":{"title":"NLT bottle 14","bottle_code":"NL_T14","bottle_img":"http:\/\/site.dev\/files\/bottles\/bottleimages\/nlt%20bottle%2014_bottle.jpg","swatch":"http:\/\/site.dev\/files\/bottles\/swatches\/nlt-bottle-14_swatch.jpg"}},{"node":{"title":"DS Bottle 033","bottle_code":"DS_033","bottle_img":"http:\/\/site.dev\/files\/bottles\/bottleimages\/ds%20bottle%20033_bottle.jpg","swatch":"http:\/\/site.dev\/files\/bottles\/swatches\/ds-bottle-033_swatch.jpg"}}]}
```

I am trying to get it with via:

```
var url = "http://site.dev/getinfo";

    $.ajax({
    url: url, 
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true, // false loads and processes the data (function) before rendering the page
    success: function(stuff){
            console.log(stuff); // <- This output of the stuff object->nodes does not show the swatch key value pair!
        process_data(stuff);
    },
    complete: function(){
        doneprocess();
    },
    error: function(code){
        error_get_data(code);
    }
});
```

but I get this **without** the swatch key|value pair. I do not know why!

```
{"nodes":[{"node":{"title":"NLT bottle 14","bottle_code":"NL_T14","bottle_img":"http://site.dev/files/bottles/bottleimages/nlt%20bottle%2014_bottle.jpg"}},{"node":{"title":"DS Bottle 033","bottle_code":"DS_033","bottle_img":"http://site.dev/files/bottles/bottleimages/ds%20bottle%20033_bottle.jpg"}}]}
```

Greatly appreciate your expertise!

Answer (score 0):

Since you munged the data we can't tell, so one obvious question is: Are you sure the JSON data structure is valid?

Check with Web Inspector or Firebug that the browser is getting the same data you think the server is sending.

Comment: What you see above is what get's displayed and received by the  ajax call. I have double-checked that I only removed additional objects from the array and changed the site name. I have checked with Firebug and the web-inspector and I get that. For some reason I can change the key name on the key value pair, change the order of the objects in the array and it will mysteriously will not pick up the swatch key | value pair.

Comment: Some days ago I had a similar problem. I stared at it for a few hours until I realized I had a temporary code stub somewhere else that'd override the data for that particular named key in the data structure. I'd suggest trying to make the example as small as possible and see if it still happens; and then go from there.